# Creating ,Writing and Reading an XML File in Android

Tags: android, xml

Basically I'm  creating an android game and want to save some data for levels in an XML file which are saved in assets folder and I parse them like :

```
final SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
final SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
final XMLReader xmlReader = sp.getXMLReader();
final XMLParser pXMLParser = new XMLParser();//My own created Class
xmlReader.setContentHandler(pXMLParser);
InputStream inputStream = Z.act.getAssets().open("levels/" + PackName + ".xml");
xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream)));
return pXMLParser.getParsedLevel();
```

Things were right until then, I was successfully able to create and save XML files. But not too much, I also wanted to create a level editor. I was able to create the XML
(in String datatype) by just using something like

(there are various "String +=" in different methods based upon call from the level editor activity/scene):

```
String XMLString = "";
XMLString += "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
....
XMLString += " </" + tagEnemy + ">"; // tagEnemy is a variable string I created
```

And I am pretty confused now If this is correct Or how should I create this dynamically in XML form (or any convinient form) and where to save(probably internal or external storage in android) should be best.Since I tried many code Fragments from finding many things on google much of my code after this may be useless and not working, but if you say i can add it.Thanks for your Help.

Comment: u can also use maven library for serialize and deserialize xml in android it quite easy

Answer (score 1):

try my code it parse the data from asset/url

```
public class SaxParserTest extends DefaultHandler {
    Boolean currentElement = false;
    String currentValue = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> datalist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> temp;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> getData(Context context ){
        try {
            SAXParserFactory saxparser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser = saxparser.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xmlReader = parser.getXMLReader();
            xmlReader.setContentHandler(SaxParserTest.this);
            /*
             * used when pick local data
             */
//              InputStream is =context.getAssets().open("data.xml");
//              xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(is));
            /*
             * used when pick data from url
             */
            URL url = new URL("http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/cd_catalog.xml");
            xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));     
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return datalist;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("CD")) {
            temp=new HashMap<String, Object>();
            temp.put(Constant.id, attributes.getValue(Constant.id));
//          temp.put(Constant.title, attributes.getValue(Constant.title));
//          temp.put(Constant.artist, attributes.getValue(Constant.artist));
//          temp.put(Constant.country, attributes.getValue(Constant.country));
//          temp.put(Constant.company, attributes.getValue(Constant.company));
//          temp.put(Constant.price, attributes.getValue(Constant.price));
//          temp.put(Constant.year, attributes.getValue(Constant.year));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        super.characters(ch, start, length);
            currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
        if(localName.equals(Constant.title))
        temp.put(Constant.title, currentValue);
        if(localName.equals(Constant.artist))
        temp.put(Constant.artist, currentValue);
        if(localName.equals(Constant.country))
        temp.put(Constant.country, currentValue);
        if(localName.equals(Constant.company))
        temp.put(Constant.company, currentValue);
        if(localName.equals(Constant.price))
        temp.put(Constant.price, currentValue);
        if(localName.equals(Constant.year))
        temp.put(Constant.year, currentValue);
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("CD"))
            datalist.add(temp);
        Log.i("DataList", datalist.toString());

    }
}
```

and use this like that

```
SaxParserTest test=new SaxParserTest();
            datal=test.getData(this);
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, datal,
                    R.layout.activity_main, new String[] { Constant.title,
                            Constant.artist, Constant.price, Constant.year,
                            Constant.company, Constant.country ,Constant.id}, new int[] {
                            R.id.txt1, R.id.txt2, R.id.txt3, R.id.txt4,
                            R.id.txt5, R.id.txt6 ,R.id.txt7});
            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Surely this is Useful, And I had implemented the Somewhat similiar approach but As I said `final XMLParser pXMLParser = new XMLParser();//My own created Class`
I can parse but having problems saving and opening such. And I will be seeing maven, thnx.